# Help Needed on re ordering and resequencing a list of rules in Java server side

Tags: java, jquery

Guys I am currently developing a web application, in which rules, which are basically sql queries are obtained from the DB and showed using Jquery sortable. These queries are running  based upon a command Sequence (1,2,3) and Status  (0,1,2 ..20 ). The command sequence tells you, in which order you have to run . Also the status field is helpful in knowing , whenever an error occurred. It  saves the value 1 or 2 ... or 20 , to help identify at which step it stopped. Below I have given a UI representation , my problem is that, when the user drags the rules, the cmdSequence and the Status have to updated in DB.

```
Ref Id   RuleNo  CmdSequence   Status
  1        1            1         0
  2        2            2         0
  3        3            1         1
  4        4            1         1
  5        5            2         2
  6        6            2         2
```

if i am moving refId 6 before refId 1 then the CmdSequence and Status should be changed. 
as below ,simillarly drag and dropping in the middle and last

```
Ref Id   RuleNo  CmdSequence   Status
  6        6            1         0
  1        1            2         0
  2        2            1         1
  3        3            2         1
  4        4            1         2
  5        5            2         2
```

i want to know how to implement in the server side , while data from browser comes from json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to detect the change and possibly be making several updates to the database after each user drags a rule up or down.